# Vite add assets path prefix / change assets path in compiled files

Tags: javascript, path, vite

Could you tell me please, how to change how vite assets path is built, but only for compiled files?
I mean, for example, I have file index.html like:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Vite App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script type="module" src="/src/main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

and here I have script with src="/src/main.js"

When I compile it, I get src="/assets/index-c371877d.js"

I am making ESP32 webserver, and because of some internal moments I need to put compiled files in another folder, on SD card.

I can change output directory using vite.config.js, here I have:

```js
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [vue(), vueJsx()],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': fileURLToPath(new URL('./src', import.meta.url))
    }
  },
  build: {
    outDir: "../../SD/modules/test", // test is project name
  },
})
```

But the problem is, that compiled files have same relative path, while I need to have modules/%moduleName%/%relative path%
So instead of src="/assets/index-c371877d.js" I need src="module/test/assets/index-c371877d.js"

I tried to change vite assetsDir:

```js
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [vue(), vueJsx()],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': fileURLToPath(new URL('./src', import.meta.url))
    }
  },
  build: {
    outDir: "../../SD/modules/test",
    assetsDir: "modules/test"
})
```

Now it adds modules/test before path, but compiled files are put into outDir + assetsDir directory, what I don't want.

Tell me please, how could I just prepend necessary path data without changing real assets directory? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solved, finally.

It was needed to provide base property for config

```js
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [vue(), vueJsx()],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': fileURLToPath(new URL('./src', import.meta.url))
    }
  },
  build: {
    outDir: Config.modulesDirRelativePath + "/vue-project"
  },
  base: "/modules/vue-project"
})
```

Comment: Worked! I wanted to change assets path from "/assets/[files]" to "./assets/[files]".  base: "./", did the trick.